# Showing that $\cos (x - \frac{\pi}{2}) = \sin x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification

> Show that$$\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{2})=\sin x .$$

I understand I have to use$$\cos(A+B)=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B .$$

Am I wrong to let $A=x$ and $B= -\frac{\pi}{2}$? Can someone please explain to me in detail how to solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: that's right. then use $sin(\pi/2)=1, cos(\pi/2)=0$.

Comment: You are nearly there.  Do you know that $\cos(\pm\pi/2) = 0$ and $\sin(\pi/2) = 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on exactly the right track. Good work!

Comment: So I have it down to 0-sinXsin(-1). I am really stumped here. I want to say the sin(x) is 1?

Comment: Not quite. We know that $\sin(-\pi/2)=-1$--not the same as $\sin(-1)$--so we have $$\cos(x-\pi/2)=0-\sin(x)\sin(-\pi/2)=-(-1)\sin(x)=\sin(x).$$

Comment: How did you arrive at sin(x)? I had 0-sinXsin(-1) but I am having trouble trying to simplify further.

Comment: You don't plug -1 into sin at the end of your expression. As Cameron stated, you simply replace $\sin{(-\pi/2)}$ with -1.

Comment: Oh I see... -sin(x)sin(-pi/2) is the same as -(sin-pi/2)sin(x) which gives us 1sin(x)=sin(x)?

Comment: That's it, precisely!